# Access table indirectly, while still allowing to update the table

Tags: sql-server

I plan to pass exam 'Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012'. I would like to better understand one question.
Question is:

> How would you accomplish this task? 
>   You work as a database developer
>   at ABC.com. ABC.com has a SQL Server 2012 database named SalesDB with
>   a table named Invoices. Application developers are developing several
>   in-house applications that will access the Invoices table. You need to
>   develop a solution that will allow the applications to access the
>   table indirectly while still allowing them to update the Invoice
>   table. How would you accomplish this task?

possible answers are.

> A. You should create a view on the Invoices table.
>
> B. You should create a columnstore index on all columns used by the
>   applications.
>
> C. You should allow the applications access to the Invoices table via
>   stored procedures.
>
> D. You should drop and recreate the Invoices table as a partitioned
>   table. Possible answers are

This is source: [How would you accomplish this task?](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/how-would-you-accomplish-this-task-13/)
They say that correct answer is C, but I don't know **why**? I think that correct is A, because view works 'indirectly' with data.
Thank for help.

Comment: But if you have a view and the user does not have permission to update the base table they can't through a view. However, if the update is made through a procedure and they have permission to execute the procedure it will work. Since you are working on your exam why don't you spin this up and test it? It wouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to build a table, assign permissions to a user, create a view and procedure. Test it out. There is nothing like learning by doing.

Comment: I'm apparently confused by the question.  I thought it was trying to address blocking and concurrency issues.   But "C" doesn't address that concern in any way that I can think of.

Comment: @TabAlleman I think the question is asking about how can you allow a user to update a table that they don't have access to. Regardless of the intention, that question is worded just awful.

Comment: In unrelated news, my test-writing consulting service has some bandwidth for new business.   I'm looking at you, Microsoft...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commented ownership-chaining of stored procs only come into place when the stored proc and the used tables have the same owner.

So I would like to point out another argument.

You can EXECUTE a stored proc AS another user. That means you could create a user without a login and grant UPDATE permissions. Let's say the name of the user is UPDATEInvoices. When you create a stored proc you can define that it has to execute as the comtext of the user.
So, when you give the user who wants to call the stored proc EXECUTE permissions he can UPDATE rows in the table because it runs with other permissions.